# How to return a boolean if any values are false in an array

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React (and Javascript) and am setting up a very simple dashboard. One component reads a JSON file (MD.json) that looks like this (shortened):

```
[
{
    "mdserver": "Medidata A",
    "mdport": "Port 1234",
    "mdstatus": true
},
{
    "mdserver": "Medidata B",
    "mdport": "Port 2345",
    "mdstatus": false
},
{
    "mdserver": "Medidata C",
    "mdport": "Port 3456",
    "mdstatus": true
}
]
```

For the dashboard, I want to create a function that checks whether any "mdstatus"-values are false. If any values are false, that means that the server is offline and the function should return "color="red"". I tried my best and this is what I came up with:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card } from "tabler-react";
import "tabler-react/dist/Tabler.css";
import md from '../../data-input/MD.json'


function Mdalert() {
    const alert = Object.keys(md).some(k => !md.[k]);
    if (alert)
        return (
            <Card.Status color="red" />
        );
    else return (
    <Card.Status color="green" />
    );
}

export default class Mdserveralert extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Mdalert />
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, I always get the "color="green"" value. Can any of you spot my mistake? Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `some` method on an array.

The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

You could check the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

You could check the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-2yu8sa)

```
md.some(k => !k.mdstatus)
```

It is better if you use `Object.values` with `some`.
If `md` is an object.
Object.values() returns an array whose elements are the values found on the object.

```
Object.values(md).some(k => !k.mdstatus)
```

Answer (score 1):

`md` is not an object, but an array, so use the `some()` directly on the md:

```
const alert = md.some(k => !k.mdstatus);
```

Comment: No problem :) :)